# Disable Textbox if Item Selected in Dropdown in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have looked all over on this site and thought I had it figured out, but I am getting this error message on `Handles`: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement".

I have a combobox dropdown and when the user selects anything from that, I need a textbox to be disabled. This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub SecondaryImage_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecondaryImage.SelectedIndexChanged

If SecondaryImage <> "" Then 'This is my comboBox dropdown
            SecondaryText.Enabled = False 'This is my textbox
        Else
            SecondaryText.Enabled = True
        End If

End Sub
```

I assume I am missing something simple, but I have no clue what. This is run through PowerPoint if that makes any difference.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That looks like VB.NET, not VBA?

Comment: Well, that would explain it if that's the case. I am pretty new to VBA. Any way to do this in VBA?

Comment: Is this on a userform?

Comment: Yes, it is on a userform.

Comment: @hunter21188 One other thing you should consider (which is strictly not related to this question) - the user may fill in the textbox value, and **then** select something from the combobox, so you may need to consider also clearing the contents of the textbox as well as disabling it.  Or perhaps disabling the combobox if anything is placed in the textbox?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, I was just working on adding a couple lines to disable the combobox if anything is placed in the textbox. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub SecondaryImage_Change()
    Me.SecondaryText.Enabled = Not Me.SecondaryImage <> ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Double negatives?!?  (Is there a reason for `Not x <> ""` rather than `x=""`?)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Pity - I thought there might have been some reason (e.g. tests for `<>""` working in some weird situations where tests for `=""` crashed out) and I would have learnt yet another new bit of useful trivia from you.

Comment: Well that's basically why I adapted the OP's code by adding the `Not` - didn't want to fall foul of something like that.